# Как сделать переход страницы на другую в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, href

Возможно, данный вопрос уже был задан, но попробую задать с моей точки зрения.

Нужно сделать переход в навигации на ru.php (рис.), возможно ли это сделать стандартной html структурой, к примеру: `<a href="ru.php">RU</a>`? Если нет, то подскажите, как сделать правильно в WordPress.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее всего сделать следующее:

1. В самом начале файла ru.php прописать комментарий /* Template Name: страница RU */ - так wordpress поймёт, что этот файл можно использовать в качестве шаблона страницы
2. В админке WP создать страницу со слагом `ru` и в правой колонке (где автор, url, изображение страницы и т.д.) выбрать нужный шаблон (в данному случае `страница RU`)
3. Опубликовать страницу, а в ссылке прописать `<a href="/ru/">RU</a>`

Тогда по ссылке Вы будете попадать на созданную движком страницу, но всё её содержимое будет по сути представлено Вашим файлом `ru.php`